# How do you get the code in the canopy editor from the ipython console?

Tags: enthought

Is it possible to get the code in the currently open editor window in the Ipython console? I am interested in running an Ipython magic function that would grab the code in the current window, and send it to a website for analysis, and then show the response in the console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but maybe the simplest approximation would be to run the ipython magic %history command and copy the output to clipboard.

Comment: I don't understand how that would help. For example I run that and get:

    %history
    %run "/var/folders/5q/lllv2yf95hg_n6h6kjttbmdw0000gn/T/tmpOgSYJ6.py"
    %history

when the editor window contains print "hello"

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding your question. Could you edit it to be clear exactly what you are trying to get from where, to where? "Window" includes the editor panel, all of its tabs, and the ipython panel.